# PyQt5 detect an alert event

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, alert

is there a way to detect when an `alert` happens on the main window? I know there is a `showEvent` and `closeEvent`, but is there an `alertEvent` equivalent?

What I am hoping to do is trigger an `alert` for the builtin [QApplication alerts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#alert) be able to detect when that alert happens but also when that alert is cleared. The alert will make the windows taskbar icon flash an orange color, and when the user brings the window back up the flashing is stopped and clears the alert.

To put it simply I want to detect when the flashing begins and when the flashing ends.

Below I will post a simple bit of code for what I am thinking.

**Main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import time



class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.start_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.start_pushButton.setText("Alert")
        self.start_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.wait)
        vbox.addWidget(self.start_pushButton)


    def wait(self):
        main_window.showMinimized()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Alert")
        app.alert(self,0)

    def event(self,evt):
        print(evt)
        return True

    def alertDetectedJob(self):
        print("Alert Detected")

    def alertClearedJob(self):
        print("Alert Cleared")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MyMainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested for Windows!

Note! On Windows, this causes the window's taskbar entry to flash for a time.
If msec is zero, the flashing will stop and the taskbar entry will turn a different
color (currently orange).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
#import time


class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.start_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.start_pushButton.setText("Alert")
        self.start_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.wait)
        vbox.addWidget(self.start_pushButton)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.flagWindowDeactivate = False                   # +++
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)       
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_func)     
        self.timer.start(5500)                              # + 5500
                                                            #   ^^
    def update_func(self):                        
        QtWidgets.QApplication.alert(self, 5000)            # + 5000
        if self.flagWindowDeactivate:                       #   ^
            self.alertDetectedJob()
        else: 
            self.alertClearedJob()

    def wait(self):
        self.showMinimized()
#        main_window.showMinimized()
#        time.sleep(2)
#        print("Alert")
#        app.alert(self, 0)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.alert(self, 5000)            # + 5000
                                                            #   ^
    def event(self, event):
#        print(event.type())
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:  # !!!
            print('WindowDeactivate')
            self.flagWindowDeactivate = True
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowActivate:    # !!!
            print('WindowActivate')
            self.flagWindowDeactivate = False
        return True
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def alertDetectedJob(self):
        print("Alert Detected")

    def alertClearedJob(self):
        print("Alert Cleared")          


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MyMainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```